# What will be the Log of killing an activity in android

Tags: java, android, debugging, error-logging, error-log

what are the details shown by the Logging mechanism in android when an activity is entered into a killing state?

Comment: You can place a Log on the method onDestroy

Comment: try reading [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: sorry, actually i want to know about the log produced while the killing process is occur.